# Marionette model data contains formatting html tags like <sup></sup>. How can I have my view honor those tags in its output?

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, handlebars.js, marionette

I'm using handlebars for my templates.  The data in my model is pulled from SQL tables.  Users enter this data in a form elsewhere.  Its medical data so sometimes the users want elements within the data to be formatted with things like superscripts. Is there a way to honor such formatting in handlebars templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Handlebars will escape everything, unless you pass your text as an instance of Handlebars.SafeString:

```
return new Handlebars.SafeString(text)
```

See the [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/) (*HTML Escaping*) or the discussion here: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/647